# Ubuntu automatically shows deleted files

Tags: usb, files, delete

I ran Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS from a live cd and I noticed that it shows deleted files (some many years old) on USB sticks and on the computer's hard drive (files that were created, saved and deleted from Windows 7, which is the os on that computer.) In a way of course, that is really cool. But how does it work? Why can I see those files automatically on Ubuntu and cannot see them from Windows 7? 
When I search for an answer to this, all I find are results telling you how to recover deleted files. But in my case, I don't need that. They are automatically there. Why are they not automatically visible for all the people out there trying to find some complicated way to get to their deleted files? Is this a feature that is only on 14.04.3?

Comment: Some programs have hidden backup files, could that be the case ?

Answer (score 1):

First: If we have a modern GUI (today all of us - only exception are dedicated servers!)
The deleting of a file - Do Not Remove the file from the system, but renames or move the file!
Windows and Unix/Linux have different ways of doing this:
In Linux Deleted files (Trash bin active) live in a hidden folder( in your File Manager pressing [Ctrl]h toggles **View Hidden Files**:

In Linux/unix all files/folders starting with a . (Dot) are hidden, in windows it is an attribute - a flag in the directory is raised - this flag is the hidden!, So they do not recognize each others way of deleting a file/folder - when recycle-bins are in use!

In Windows Trash-bin is called $Recycled - Windows creates a link to the file in $Recycled folder and renames - changes the first character with the Greek lower case letter Tau (death).

In Linux the folder is named  .Trash-[UID] (in my system it is .Trash-1000 my userID is 1000 if you have more users there will be more files with growing numbers each user have their own trash-bin)

Deleting files in the other OS is a bad idea, because: Deleting from a foreign OS only handles the native trash-bin and not the others.

Linux actually moves the file to the hidden directory.

Try viewing the hidden files on your USB-stick, you will find the .Trash-(some number) directory, which you have not emptied!! :-(

Windows think the disk (pen) is corrupt if you delete windows owned files from Linux, Linux tries to correct the file names and show them!

Actually it is VERY ANNOYING to have to empty the trash every time we have finished using a USB-device for transferring purpose - this is why we all seems to loose storage on our removable devices! ( Deleted files are mostly all there still !!)

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I understood your answer entirely. Here is  more detail about what happened: I deleted all the files from a USB stick on Windows many years ago on a totally different computer. When I put the USB on Linux I could see the deleted files. I put the USB back on another Windows computer and unhid all folders and STILL could not see the deleted files. I put the USB back on the linux computer and COULD see the deleted files. That is what confuses me.

Comment: If you delete these files in linux and empty the Trash, they will deleted for good.

Comment: You can always use the direct delete (Shift+Del) to skip the Recycling Bin.  You can also tell the OS you're using to stop using a recycle bin for that device. In addition to that the reason you see less space on a removable drive is the MiB and MB thing plus formatting.

Comment: @Avamander Yes i know, but I do like to have the easy undo delete in my homefolder ( sometimes even I am a tad too enthusiastic deleting files - so to my rescue the recycle-bin )
But I do some testing on removable HD's on the TV!
Testing recording levels, in Handbrake - multible subtitles. and such! so on those devises HD's and big 64GB sticks I really do not want the recycle-bin - it is all just test, and the device is reformatted afterwards !!